# Сравнение контактов телефонной книги и сервера

Tags: android, контакты

Пишу программу для совместной работы с некоторыми документами. Авторизация пользователей будет через номер мобильного телефона. 
Хочу прикрутить функционал поиска авторизованных пользователей в локальной телефонной книги.
Например чтоб при запуске программы произошло сравнение пользователей в телефонной книге и на сервере, и при совпадении было сообщение - "У Василия Петрова тоже стоит эта программа".
Возможно уже есть какие-то практики как это правильно делать или вообще готовые механизмы.
Пока решение загонять все номера из телефонной книги в массив и слать их на сервер для анализа.  И возможно как то их шифровать, а то первое решение совсем дикое в плане персональных данных.
Как с этим справляются различные мессенжеры Viber,WathUp и тд

Comment: а вы у Василия Петрова спросили разрешение на показ что у него стоит?

Comment: да, там будет соглашение для авторизованных пользователей. Меня больше волнует, что приходится отправлять все номера, в том числе и тех кто не пользуется программой

Comment: вас не пропустят в Google Play

Comment: А всякие месенжеры, они же скорее всего так же работаю? Или им поблажки из-за громкого имени? Как еще они узнают что например моя мама теперь пользуется Viber

Comment: конечно поблажки, вам никто не позволит ковыряться и раздавать налево направо конфиденциальные данные телефонной книги, гайки закручены до упора